# Need help writing custom filter function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter, undefined, each

I've written an `each()` function, which works correctly, that behaves exactly the same as underscore's `_.each()`. I'd like to write a function that's sort of similar to `filter()`, but instead returns `true` or `false` for each element that is run through the callback/predicate function.

```
var filter = function(collection, callback){
    each(collection, function(item){
            if (callback(item)) {return true;}
            else {return false}
        });
};

console.log(filter([1,2,3,4,5], function(x) {return x % 2 == 0;}));
```

This is what I have, but it's returning `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Normally" `.filter()` returns the elements of an array where a predicate evalutes to `true`. What you're describing is exactly what `.map()` is for. Therefor you (maybe) should rename your function

Comment: @Andreas, map returns something for *every* element.

Comment: @NinaScholz I know... And that's exactly what the OP wants: "_but instead returns true or false for each element..._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious ; you return true of false in your each method.

From the filter function point of view you return nothing.

If you want to write a filter function you should do something like this :

```
var filter = function(collection, callback){
    var result = [];
    each(collection, function(item){
            result.push((callback(item))?true:false);
        } 
    );
    return result;  
};
```

Another possibility would be to modify your each so it returns an array that contains each value that has been return inside.

Comment: I tried re-writing your function so that it would console.log the truthiness as it iterated, and while it did so, in the end it also returned `undefined`. Do you know why? I changed the anonymous function's body to `console.log(((callback(item)) ? true : false));`.

Comment: write both line :  result.push((callback(item))?true:false); console.log(((callback(item)) ? true : false)); or you'll return an empty array

Comment: I forgot to mention that I commented out `var result = [];` and `return result`. In this case, why does it return undefined? I don't want it to return anything, I just want to console.log it

Comment: It's javascript, if you don't return a thing from a function it will return undefined. Just don't log the value returned by your filter function then :)

Comment: I'm not sure you get what I'm asking. How can I modify your code so that it only logs true or false for each element (and won't return undefined)?

Comment: As i said if you define a function filter() that return nothing and do var j = filter(); j will have the value "undefined". This is how it works in javascript. Just don't use "console.log(filter());" then.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function doesn't return anything. Try returning the result from your each() call.